# What do these `<qt>` tags mean?

Tags: qt, tags, notifications

While browsing the [Kopete source code](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdenetwork/kopete/repository) I've noticed that all the notification strings are enclosed in `<qt>` tags, but I can't seem to find any information about what these are supposed to do. Here's an [example](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdenetwork/kopete/repository/revisions/master/entry/protocols/jabber/jabberaccount.cpp#L562) showing what I mean.

The notifications from Kopete show without any sign of the `<qt>` markup when rendered in knotify, but other notification daemons show the `<qt>` tags so I'm assuming this is something specific to Qt. What is the purpose of these tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a custom tag of Qt's richtext implementation, and synonym to `<html>`. The [Qt richtext documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html) says:

> Synonym for html. Provided for compatibility with earlier versions of Qt

In previous version, the rich text support was even further away from full HTML support, so using `<html>` would have been misleading.

It's commonly used to wrap rich text/HTML and will also ensure that QLabels configured to Qt::AutoText (HTML vs. plain text auto-detection) will switch to HTML. If the other notification demons can handle HTML enclosed in `<html>`, it might be worth to convert those strings. (Not sure what the best practices regarding that in KDE are these days).